# How to remove every second pixel from the HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have already create code [jsfiddle.net/NHj2t](http://jsfiddle.net/NHj2t/) for downsample image, but I have one issue: on the canvas I have duplicate image, and I don't understand why - please explain me.

```
function downsample(srcImageData, width, height) {
   var backContext = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
   var result = backContext.createImageData(width, height);
   var d = 0;
   for (var p = 0; p < srcImageData.data.length; p += 8) {
        result.data[d] = srcImageData.data[p];
        result.data[d + 1] = srcImageData.data[p + 1];
        result.data[d + 2] = srcImageData.data[p + 2];
        result.data[d + 3] = srcImageData.data[p + 3];
        d += 4;
   }
   srcImageData = result;
   return srcImageData;
}
```

How to remove every second pixel from the canvas?

I want downsample an image.
I trying to implement Gaussian Pyramid in JavaScript 
[info 1](http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~maov/classes/vision08/lect/07_Pyramids.pdf)

I do not understand English well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are taking every second pixel, but only horizontally. To get what you want you need to also skip every second pixel vertically. After you processed `width` number of pixels you want to skip a whole line of pixels, i.e. jump `width` pixels forward. I hope you understand what I am trying to say.

```
var backContext = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
var skip = 2;
var result = backContext.createImageData(width/skip, height/skip);
var d = 0;
for (var y = 0; y < height; y += skip) {
    for (var x = 0; x < width; x += skip) {
        for (var c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
            result.data[d++] = srcImageData.data[(y*width+x)*4+c];
        }
    }
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NHj2t/2/

Answer (score 1):

You are basically creating two interleaved versions of the original image, one odd line and one even line.

By skipping 2 pixels in source you will only draw half the lines where one "lags" behind resulting in two lines side-by-side (every other line, hence "interleaved"). If you want to to this by pixel iteration you need to calculate and consider vertical position too.

Why not use `drawImage` to down-sample your image?

```
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width * 0.5, img.height * 0.5);
```

This will draw your image at 50% size.

**[Modified fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/NHj2t/1/)**

Comment: Why not use drawImage to down-sample your image? - because I don't know how this - good or not for algorithm - maybe all ok, but I every time see information about removing every even rows and columns(of pictures represented in matrix form), or about removing every second pixel

Comment: @452 Removing every other pixel is basically just sub-sampling. You won't get blur nor low-passfiltering. By using the built-in drawImage you will at least achieve a form of "blur" in form of interpolated pixels. If you want to use just sub-sampling you will need to pre-filter (gaussian blur) the image first.

Comment: yes, you right, but I afraid about downvotes http://jsfiddle.net/NHj2t/4/ I add gaussian blur - but maybe something is wrong with a kernel.